# Use Selenium to get facebook "seemore" button

Tags: python, selenium, facebook

I want to scrape the content of the top ten posts on my fan page, but the content is hidden and I need to press "seemore", but I can't find the corresponding location with Selenium.
This problem has been bothering me for a long time, hope someone can help
PS: Non-native English speakers, please forgive me if the useful words are inappropriate

1. ```
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="jsc_c_1m"\]/div/div/span/div\[2\]/div\[3\]/div').click()
   ```
2. ```
   button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="jsc_c_y4"\]/div/div/span/div\[2\]/div\[3\]/div')
   driver.excute_script("arguments\[0\].click();",button)
   ```
3. ```
   driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,'seemore').click()
   ```

Comment: We would need to see HTML code in order to provide you a robust relative path.

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them? And if you get banned you know why. Also be aware that the Facebook HTML changes all the time. So even if you get it to work it will stop working any day.